# Aligning horizontal panels inside a vertical panel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have two horizontalpanel inside a vertical panel, the horizontalpanels consist of a label and a textbox. Is there anyway I can align the textboxes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBu1W.jpg

```
    //create a vertical panel
    VerticalPanel vpanel = new VerticalPanel();

    //create a hortizontal panel for customer name
    HorizontalPanel hcustomer = new HorizontalPanel();
    hcustomer.setSpacing(2);
    Label customerlabel = new Label("Customer Name: ");
    final TextBox customerTb = new TextBox();
    hcustomer.add(customerlabel);
    hcustomer.add(customerTb);

    //create a horizontal panel for caller number
    HorizontalPanel hcaller = new HorizontalPanel();
    hcaller.setSpacing(2);
    Label callerlabel = new Label("Caller Number: ");
    final TextBox callerTb = new TextBox();
    hcaller.add(callerlabel);
    hcaller.add(callerTb);
    callerTb.setMaxLength(10);
    callerTb.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
            reformatPhone(callerTb);
        }
    });

    //add widget into vpanel
    vpanel.add(hcustomer);
    vpanel.add(hcaller);
```

I figured I can manually do setspacing in the hortizontalpanel to align them up but again I figure there has to be an easier way.

Comment: I think you are going to need to share your code so that people can advise you what to change.

Comment: Sure thing. I added my code.

Comment: If you're still using horizontal/vertical panels in 2015, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you're still using horizontal/vertical panels in 2015, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: And what method do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
vpanel.setWidth("100%");

hcustomer.setWidth("100%");

hcaller.setWidth("100%");
```